# Embedding Google forms in IFRAME causes Http 302 redirect loop in chrome, but firefox works

Tags: wordpress, http, iframe, http-status-code-302

After upgrading to Wordpress 5.4.2

Loading an Google Form in an Iframe fails after redirection loop, which starts with a changed url with the added parameters
like `https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https..`

[image: loop as seen in chrome dev tools]

PHP is 7.4
everything is https

What is =[ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact cause because of policy change.

[image: no file uploads via embed]